# pass a nested array of params to laravel request object

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to pass a params object with two attributes,

- an ID
- an array

to Laravel and access the properties through the `$request` object. I am getting the error shown below. How can I accomplish this?

Angular:

```
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url + 'questions/check',
                cache: true,
                params: {
                    id: params.question_id, // 1
                    choices: params.answer_choices // [3, 2]
                }
            });
```

Laravel:

```
    $input = $request->all();

    return $input; //output: {choices: "2", id: "1"}

    return $input['choices'];  //output: 2
```

Clearly, the nested `choices` array (which should be `[3, 2]`) is not getting passed through here.

I've also tried following [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input), which state:

> When working on forms with "array" inputs, you may use dot notation to
>   access the arrays:
>
> $input = Request::input('products.0.name');

I tried:

```
    $input = $request->input('choices.1'); //should get `2`

    return $input;
```

Which returns nothing.

---

EDIT: I can tell the choices array is being sent with both values 3 and 2, but am not sure how to get them from the Laravel Request object:

Request URI: `GET /api/questions/check?choices=3&choices=2&id=1 HTTP/1.1`

Response from:

```
    $input = $request->all();

    return $input;
```

[image]

Comment: mm try adding [] on params: [{}], then access input[0]['choices']

Comment: @melvnberd I don't see how this helps. Also, the $http AJAX call needs to send an object, not an array

Comment: what do you see in the url in browser dev tools network?

Comment: @charlietfl see above please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the key in the same way you would build a url-formatted form request.

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url + 'questions/check',
    cache: true,
    params: {
        id: params.question_id, // 1
        "choices[]": params.answer_choices // [3, 2]
    }
});
```

The server will then receive your request like `questions/check?id=1&choices[]=3&choices[]=2`

The `$http` service flattens your params into a query string. For some reason it's not smart enough to add the brackets which are required in order for the server to read your query string as an array.